# Trouble in reproducing analytical calculations numerically

Tags: python, numpy, vector, linear-algebra, physics

I've been trying to reproduce some calculations that consist basically in calculating the time evolution of a certain initial wave vector in an Aubry-André Hamiltonian. I've already done other calculations with the model and checked to see that both the energies and the vectors that I've calculated are correct.

The calculation pretty much consists in calculating the variance, which, for this problem is defined as $var = \Sqrt(\sum(n - n_{0})^{2}|\psi(t)|^{2})$

So my problem is calculating the $\psi(t)$ part, which pretty much goes as follows: Define a matrix S which has its columns given by the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian (which I know to be right), then define the time evolution unitary operator as it usually is ($E = e^{-i \epsilon t}) where $\epsilon$ are the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian (also correct) and then multiply the adjoint S operator on the right side. So we get something like $S E S^{\dagger} \psi_{0}$.

If we do this recursively n times, we get the initial state evolved all the way to a time t_n, which is what I want so that I can calculate the variance. For some reason, my results are pretty distant from what I expected, which is this:

[image: this]

and what i get is this:

[image: this]

I'll include my code bellow and would be very grateful if anyone could point out the issue in it.

```py
E = np.diag(energias) #check
S = np.column_stack(vetores) #check
S_dagger = np.conjugate(S.T) #check


n0 = (N+1)//2

psi_0 = np.zeros(N-1) #initial state = delta function around the middle of the lattice
psi_0[n0] = 1.

phi_0 = np.dot(S_dagger, psi_0) #avoids making the same multiplication more than 1 time, defines a new initial state

tlim = np.linspace(0.1, 100, 1000)

#evolução temporal de psi_0 na rede

psi_t = []

for t in tlim:
    U = np.exp(-1j * E * t)
    var_mult = np.dot(U, phi_0)
    psi_evo = np.dot(S, var_mult)
    
    psi_t.append(psi_evo)

variance = []
a = 0
for n in range(len(tlim)):
    x = (np.abs(psi_t[n]))**2
    expr = np.sqrt(np.sum((n-n0)**2*x))
    variance.append(expr)
```

I'm also including the hamiltonian part but, as i said, i'm sure that this part works as it should

```
def hamiltoniano(t, l, N, fase):
    d = -l * np.cos(2 * pi * G * np.arange(1, N) + fase)
    e = -t * np.ones(N-2)

    tridiagonal_matrix = np.diag(d) + np.diag(e, k=-1) + np.diag(e, k=1)

    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eigh(tridiagonal_matrix)
    return eigenvalues, eigenvectors, tridiagonal_matrix
N = 100  # N = L (tamanho da rede)


energias, vetores, hamiltonian = hamiltoniano(t, l, N, fase)
```

Thank you !

PS. It doesn't seem like the equations are working (?)

Comment: Since we don't have _energias_, this cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

You have TWO major problems:

U should be a diagonal matrix with complex exponentials of unit magnitude along the diagonal - but in your code it is not (because exp(0)=1, not 0, so U ends up a rather "full" matrix).

You are working out the variance (actually, standard deviation) incorrectly. In your code, n is associated with time level, not position in the lattice as it should be.

I am having to guess at some of the parameters sent to hamiltoniano(), because you haven't provided them. However, the following may help. (Plotted on log-log axes, as in your target diagram.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def hamiltoniano(t, l, N, fase):
    d = -l * np.cos(2 * np.pi * G * np.arange(1, N) + fase)
    e = -t * np.ones(N-2)

    tridiagonal_matrix = np.diag(d) + np.diag(e, k=-1) + np.diag(e, k=1)

    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eigh(tridiagonal_matrix)
    return eigenvalues, eigenvectors, tridiagonal_matrix


N = 100    # N = L (tamanho da rede)
# The following are a complete guess ...
l = N
t = 1.0
G = 1.0
fase = 0.0

energias, vetores, hamiltonian = hamiltoniano(t, l, N, fase)
S = np.column_stack(vetores)
S_dagger = np.conjugate( S.T )


psi_0 = np.zeros(N-1)              #initial state = delta function around the middle of the lattice
n0 = (N+1)//2
psi_0[n0] = 1.

phi_0 = np.dot( S_dagger, psi_0 ) 
log10t = np.linspace( -1.0, 7, 1000 )

times = []
standard_deviation = []

for lg in log10t:
    t = 10 ** lg
    U = np.diag( np.exp( -1j * energias * t ) )
    psi = np.dot( S, np.dot(U, phi_0) )
    expr = 0
    for pos in range( N - 1 ):
        expr += ( pos - n0 ) ** 2 * abs( psi[pos] ) ** 2
    times.append( t )
    standard_deviation.append( np.sqrt( expr ) )

plt.loglog( times, standard_deviation )
plt.show()
```

[image]